# Why can't the Opsview_rest Perl script not find the OPSVIEW_URL_PREFIX Environment variable using $ENV{var} while it has been set on CentOS6?

Tags: perl, rest, environment-variables, centos6

**Aim**

The aim is to run Opsview_rest Perl script.

---

**Attempt**

*Attempt 1*

```
sudo /usr/local/nagios/bin/opsview_rest --username=admin --password=initial GET config/host/1
```

*Attempt 2*

Print statements were added to check whether the Perl script could retrieve the environment variable.

```
my $url_prefix = $ENV{OPSVIEW_URL_PREFIX} || "http://localhost";

print $url_prefix;
print $ENV{OPSVIEW_URL_PREFIX};
print $url_prefix;
```

---

**Expected outcome**

The Opsview_rest Perl script calls the environment variable OPSVIEW_URL_PREFIX and use it to execute the commands in the script

---

**Current outcome**

*Current outcome 1*

```
Can't connect to localhost:80 (Connection refused)
```

*Current outcome 2*

Although the variable has been set

```
[root@vm-one libexec]# echo $OPSVIEW_URL_PREFIX
http://localhost:3000
```

the Perl script cannot retrieve it from the environment.

```
[root@vm-one libexec]# sudo /usr/local/nagios/bin/opsview_rest --username=admin --password=initial GET config/host/1
http://localhosthttp://localhostCan't connect to localhost:80 (Connection refused)

LWP::Protocol::http::Socket: connect: Connection refused at /usr/local/nagios/bin/../perl/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.

Goto undefined subroutine &Carp::shortmess_real at /usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm line 41.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @TLP a environment variable OPSVIEW_URL_PREFIX cannot be found by the Perl script while this has been set on the system. $ENV{OPSVIEW_URL_PREFIX} does not find the var while the expectation was that it should be able to find it using this

Comment: @TLP While the echo on the system indicates that the system can find the variable the Perl script should be able to call it using `$ENV{OPSVIEW_URL_PREFIX}`? It does not seem to find it when I print the output. I do not understand why.

Comment: `sudo` is stripping it.

Comment: @hobbs I have added the env to the root user env and it can be echod from there as well

Comment: @utrecht you mean in profile or something? sudo doesn't respect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to debug problems like this is to strip them to to the simplest possible thing that demonstrates the problem.

Here is a perl "one-liner" that shows that @hobbs is correct, that `sudo` is stripping the password.

```
$ TESTY=foo sudo perl -le 'print "The value is $ENV{TESTY}..."'
The value is ...
$ TESTY=foo perl -le 'print "The value is $ENV{TESTY}..."'
The value is foo...
```

The first try is running with `sudo`, and $TESTY is not printed, the second try runs *without* `sudo`, and the environment variable comes through fine.

Now, to actually answer your question, since `sudo` gives you root privileges, and because environment variables can change the behavior of programs in all kinds of ways, `sudo` is really diligent about cleaning up the environment when it runs. This being unix, you can change the behavior.  For instance the -E flag might work for you,

```
$ TESTY=foo sudo -E perl -le 'print "The value is $ENV{TESTY}..."'
The value is foo...
```

see `man sudo` for details of what it's doing, and especially the "SECURITY NOTES" section of the man page.